# How to do brace expansion tab-completion, for filenames in vim?

Tags: vim, tab-completion, brace-expansion

In vim (and bash), you can specify alternatives in filenames, eg:

```
:arga project/html/{index,sitemap}.html
```

This expands to "project/html/index.html" and "project/html/sitemap.html" (the `:arga` appends them both to the argument list; you can get to them with `:n`).

Now, vim already does some filename completion on this, with `TAB`, by cycling through the possibilities. For the above example, it would show the index one, then the sitemap one, then back to the original text.

I to be able to type this much:

```
:arga project/html/{in
```

and press `TAB`, and have it complete (even though I'm in the middle of a brace):

```
:arga project/html/{index.html
```

and have tab-completion also work for the next one, from `project/html/{index.html,sit` to `project/html/{index.html,sitemap.html`.

Is there already an option in vim to do this?  If not, how would you implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is possible, you'll have to define your own :Arga command and to specify your own expansion function. However as vim has a few things hard-coded in regard of command-line completion, I can't guaranty you that this is possible.

You can have a look at my [:SearchIn* commands](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/SiR/trunk/plugin/searchInRuntime.vim) for examples.